# iOS - Identify what UIViewController was previously shown in a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I need to identify what `UIViewController` was previously shown in a `UINavigationController`. My navigation is 3 levels deep, in level 2 I need to identify if I got here from pushing from level 1 or if I got here from popping from level 3. How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate method:

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and query it to find out the currently displayed view controller:

```
 navigationController.topViewController
```

This is the one you're coming from.

Comment: I may be daft but I don't get it. I implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method in my level 2 viewcontroller. And when I `NSLog(@"%@",navigationController.topViewController);` I just get the current `UIViewController` (level 2) that is currently displaying (not the level 3 view controller or level 1 view controller that I navigated from).

Comment: @PeterWarbo you're not daft, I am.  Sorry about that.  There is no easy way, but here is an approach that should work.  Whatever class instantiates your nav controller, make it a KVO (Key-Value observer) of the navigationController.topViewController property.  Whenever this property changes, it will call observeValueForKeyPath: and supply a dictionary of changes in the context parameter.  From this you can determine what the old value was.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the entire UINavigationController stack by using the the viewControllers property.

```
int count = [navigationController.viewControllers count];

topController = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:count - 1];
previousController = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:count - 2];
//...
//...
rootController = [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: count - count];
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5.0 added [[UIViewController isMovingToParentViewController]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingToParentViewController).  During `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, this returns `YES` if you're coming from a lower-numbered view controller, `NO` otherwise.  The name is unfortunately confusing - you would think that [[UIViewController isMovingFromParentViewController]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController) would be the correct method to call.

However, on behalf of all cheapskates whose second generation devices are stuck at iOS 4.2.1, please don't use iOS 5 features unless you really have to.